# STARTTLS timeout with GMail on a slow processor

Tags: c, ssl

We have a datalogger running a relatively slow processor (7.3 MHz) that has instructions to send email using SMTP.  The datalogger operating system uses axTLS to support TLS connections.  When connecting to a service, such as GMail, that requires the use of TLS, it can take the datalogger some time (12 seconds or more) to perform the calculations required to complete the handshake.  While this is taking place, GMail times out our client connection.  Is there some kind of SSL heartbeat or keepalive message that can be sent while the datalogger finishes the required calculations?

Comment: And yet security-minded people keep insisting that the overhead of TLS never causes problems... Probably the easiest solution is to send the data to your own server, instead of GMail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the RFC (RFC 6520) that discusses the HeartBeatRequest extension for TLS.  This RFC has the following text:

```
A HeartbeatRequest message can arrive almost at any time during the
lifetime of a connection.  Whenever a HeartbeatRequest message is
received, it SHOULD be answered with a corresponding
HeartbeatResponse message.

However, a HeartbeatRequest message SHOULD NOT be sent during
handshakes.  If a handshake is initiated while a HeartbeatRequest is
still in flight, the sending peer MUST stop the DTLS retransmission
timer for it.  The receiving peer SHOULD discard the message
silently, if it arrives during the handshake.
```

This leads me to believe that, although it MAY be possible to extend the handshake time out, it is unlikely to do so.

Comment: Please note that Heartbeat is not implemented in all SSL stacks. I think it was first implemented in OpenSSL 1.0.1 and since it cause the infamous  [Heartbleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed) attack there this extension was not well received.  For example the OpenSSL fork LibreSSL removed this extension as one of their first actions after the fork.

Answer (score 1):

Just imagine that all clients would take such a long time with the SSL handshake. This would tie up lots of resources at the server and would actually more resemble a denial of service attempt like [slowloris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(software)).

Thus it is expected from the client to be a nicely behaving citizen on the internet and be fast enough to be handle the handshake in a short time. Using a processor with a speed which was state of the art 30 years ago simply is not sufficient to connect against services which are designed to be used by current clients.

Thus if you want to use such services from a lowest-end device you should instead transmit the data to your own relay server which is willing to wait such a long time and this relay can then deliver the data with the expected speed to the public servers.

Comment: The reason why our equipment is designed the way it is is because it is meant to work at extremely low power and at extreme temperature conditions ... something that can't be said for most "citizens on the internet".  You have partially answered my question with a fair amount of snobbery.  To be honest, the RFC, which stated that the keep-alive should not be used during the handshake, was more helpful.

Comment: @JonTrauntvein: Sorry for you that you see it this way. I've only tried to point out that you are trying to use an interface (gmail) which is not designed for dealing with slow clients but was designed with "normal" users in mind. To deal with the use case of really slow clients you envision gmail would need to provide more resources than they do with the expected use case.